# Difference Between Methods in Python

Tags: python, exception

I am new to python programming, and I've now reached the section on OOP in the Python book. I am confused about method definitions in python classes.

What is the difference between:

```
def __add__(self):
  pass
```

and

```
def add(self):
  pass
```

I'll be thankful if you could clarify this for me; thank you guys.

Comment: Usually an underscore at the beginning means that its meant for use internally for that object and not for public use. EDIT: it was single underscores originally, with double underscores it means you are implementing the behavior of `object + object`

Comment: well they are different names (also the one with underscores is a special magic function)

Comment: __add__ is used to defined the addition (with a "+") operation, see here: http://effbot.org/pyref/__add__.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods that begin and end with underscores like `__add__(...)` can be used to override existing functionality while a method like `add(...)` without the underscores is a new user-defined method. The difference would be:

With `__add__(self)` , you could call
    `thisObj + otherObj`

With `add(self)`, you would call
    `thisObj.add(otherObj)`

So `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__call__`, etc. override existing operators or functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, there is no difference. One is a method called `__add__` and the other is a method called `add`.

However, this is a convention which the Python interpreter, and various libraries, use to designate methods that are somehow "special". They are called **magic methods**. For example, `a + b` is essentially syntactic sugar for `a.__add__(b)`. Really:

```
>>> (1).__add__(2)
3
```

This means if you create a class for which you want addition to be meaningful, instead of calling your method, say, `addTo` and then doing `foo.addTo(bar)`, you can call the method `__add__` and do `foo + bar` instead.

Other magic methods: `a - b` is equivalent to `a.__sub__(b)`, `len(a)` is equivalent to `a.__len__()`, `cmp(a, b)` is equivalent to `a.__cmp__(b)`. `a = MyClass()` causes the new object's `__init__` method to be called. [And many more](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

Methods in Python with double underscores before and after their names are called commonly called [magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html), and are used to define certain behaviours for objects.

For example the `my_object.__add__()` method would be implicitly called when your object was used as part of an addition

```
>>> my_object + another_object
```

Here is a [good resource](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) of Python’s magic methods, aka “dunder” methods.